# Quarkus with EclipseLink?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, quarkus

Is it possible to use EclipseLink with QUarkus? Or is Quarkus too hardly coupled with Hibernate?

We are in the process of choosing our MP implementation and we want to stick as close to the reference impls as possible

I am not seeing much information on https://quarkus.io/guides/ or even this very forum to indicate that eclipselink too can be used with Quarkus.

Any pointers on why Quarkus is tied so tightly to a specific impl (if it is) of JPA would also be welcome

TIA

Rahul

Answer (score 6):

You can use EclipseLink by adding it in your classpath as fxrobin mentioned. But it won't work for native image generation, nor will be integrated with the database connection pool, the transaction enlistment etc. Finally the startup time will be much longer.

The reason Quarkus focuses on Hibernate ORM is exactly for these reasons. Making Hibernate ORM work on native, making it do work at build time to speed startup time, smoothly integrating it with other areas takes a lot of time. Someone could make the same for EclipseLink with a few months of work ahead of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can add EclipseLink in a class way as if you were in Java SE. But then you have to manage the transactional behaviour by code but not with annotations.